# Allure reports folder created but no report seen in the folder

Tags: allure

I have added the required dependencies in my `POM.xml` and also added the required plugin in the runner class. But when I run, I see that the allure reports folder is created and it has a json file. I don't see the html report generated. Am I missing something here? My plugin code is below.

```
plugin = { "pretty", "html:target/cucumber-html-reports", "io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm",
        "json:target/cucumber-html-reports/cucumber.json"}
```

Ideally there should be a html report which is generated.

Below is the part of pom.xml for the surefire reports

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.19.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <argLine>
                            -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                            -Dcucumber.options="--plugin io.qameta.allure.cucumberjvm.AllureCucumberJvm"
                        </argLine>
                    </configuration>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
                            <version>${aspectj.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please add pom.xml

Comment: Added the code from pom.xml

Comment: I am awaiting some response to this question still.

Comment: Is somebody still looking at this thread? Seems like nobody is able to fix this.